# Posting data from two different forms in laravel?

Tags: php, forms, post, laravel, laravel-4

I have a log in and register form that I'd like to set up on the same page.

The log in form works just fine, with dummy data already inputted in to the database that i'm using.

The issue I'm having is that I'm getting a method calling error (assumedly because I have the same post function call to two different functions.

Currently in my routes.php file I have

```
    // route to process the form
Route::post('/', array('uses' => 'HomeController@doLogin'));

Route::post('/', array('uses' => 'HomeController@doRegister'));
```

And my controller file looks like this (sorry it's a little long, I thought it'd be better to provide everything instead of assuming someone can understand my question from just my explanation alone)

```
public function doRegister() {
    $v = User::validate(Input::all());

    if ( $v->passes() ) {
            User::create(array(
                    'name'=>      Input::get('name'),
                    'email'=>     Input::get('email'),
                    'password'=>  Hash::make(Input::get('password')),
            ));

            return 'Thanks for registering!';
    } else {
            return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors($v->getMessages());
    }
}

public function doLogin()
{
    // validate the info, create rules for the inputs
    $rules = array(
        'email'    => 'required|email', // make sure the email is an actual email
        'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3' // password can only be alphanumeric and has to be greater than 3 characters
    );

    // run the validation rules on the inputs from the form
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    // if the validator fails, redirect back to the form
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('/')
            ->withErrors($validator) // send back all errors to the login form
            ->withInput(Input::except('password')); // send back the input (not the password) so that we can repopulate the form
    } else {

        // create our user data for the authentication
        $userdata = array(
            'email'     => Input::get('email'),
            'password'  => Input::get('password')
        );

        // attempt to do the login
        if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {

            // validation successful!
            // redirect them to the secure section or whatever
            // return Redirect::to('secure');
            // for now we'll just echo success (even though echoing in a controller is bad)
            echo 'SUCCESS!';

        } else {        

            // validation not successful, send back to form 
            return Redirect::to('/');

        }

    }
}
```

As far as I'm aware this is because I'm not setting which function to use correctly for my registration form.

Hopefully I've done an ok job at explaining my issue, any solution please? (rather new to laravel)

Comment: The script will never hit the register route. It reads from top top bottom, and will only respond to 1, and since the URI is the same, the doLogin method will always be called. So as it stands, there is no way to register.

Comment: @jah is there a way of distinguishing between the two form posts within the same controller function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One form would post to login and the other to register

```
Route::post('login', array('uses' => 'HomeController@doLogin'));
Route::post('register', array('uses' => 'HomeController@doRegister'));
```

And then you would open the form like:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login')) }}
```

and

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'register')) }}
```

Edit:
And the forms would just be placed inside your home view for example, and then you would just redirect from the login and register methods, and not show a view.